# Suspicious iOS App

Tags: ios, applications, security, ios-appstore

I was looking through purchases members of my family made through Apple's Family Sharing feature, when I stumbled across a suspicious-looking app, "OneClick Cleaner Pro" (image below). This app's page has a lowercase "update" button, which is suspicious for 2 reasons: 1) normally the update button is uppercase and 2) as far as I can tell, this app is not installed on my phone (searching for it in the app library yields no results).

This app does not show up in an app store search but "One Click Cleaner Pro" (with a space between "one" and "click") does. I believe that neither my own device nor my family member's device has been deliberately jailbroken.

Any ideas what's going on?

[image: sus OneClick Cleaner Pro]

Comment: How are you viewing the family purchase history?

Comment: @fsb In the iOS app store, I go to the profile icon, then Purchased, then I select the family member there, then I see their purchases

Answer (score 1):

This could be an app that's no longer for sale, the name has changed, or there's other App Store or developer restrictions that prevent it from being seen when searching.

When I searched the web for this app, I saw a privacy policy result from a app named TurboCleaner Pro from Loop Lead Consulting, the same company in your screenshot:

[image]

You should go to [Apple's report a problem](https://reportaproblem.apple.com) site and complete the form about this app.